# Get variables from a list and use them in an IF statement

Tags: php

I have a separated list "category*value", separated by semicolons:

```
$list = 'category1*value1;category2*value2;category3*value3;'
```

What would be the best way to get these elements into a variable, or array and use them in an IF statement?

```
    if ( $main_category  == //category1..2..3// ){
       echo 'Category:' . //category1..2..3// . 'Value:' //value1..2..3//
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you create a string-keyed PHP array?

Comment: Do you want to check if `$main_category` is contained in that _list_, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd explode that string into arrays, or, if it's possible, store it as an array in the first place. so:

```
<?php
$main_category = 'category1';

$list = 'category1*value1;category2*value2;category3*value3;';

$listitems = explode(';', $list);
// Split the string on the ';', look:
// var_dump($listitems);

$catlist = array();
foreach ($listitems as $item) {
  $parts = explode('*', $item);
  if (count($parts) == 2) {
    $catlist[$parts[0]] = $parts[1];
  }
}
// See what happened. Array is now in cat => value format.
//var_dump($catlist);

if (array_key_exists($main_category, $catlist)) {
  echo "Category: $main_category, {$catlist[$main_category]}";
}
```

But it's easier to store it like that right away. That way you don't need the for loop at all, and the category list becomes easier to read as well:

```
$catlist = array(
  'category1' => 'value1',
  'category2' => 'value2',
  'category3' => 'value3',
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
$list = 'category1*value1;category2*value2;category3*value3;';
$a = (explode(";", $list));
$b = implode("*", $a);
$c = explode("*", $b);
```

Now $c will contain the category and value as an array. in every odd position there will be category, and in the every even position there will be value. 
You can write loops accordingly to access each element.
Hope this help..